# Supported http cipher suites in go?

Tags: go, ssl, encryption

Does go support any of these cipher suites for http client?

- AES128-SHA
- AES256-SHA
- DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
- DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
- ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

I get handshake failure when connecting to the server.

**Update:**

I read one .p12 and one .pem file into a tls.Config that is then used in http.Transport. The final line client.Post returns error "handshake failure" which is not very helpful.

I bit of digging reveled that the ciphers above are those permitted on the server.

```golang
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("cert.p12")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)

    }
    rootCA, err := ioutil.ReadFile("rootcert.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("reading cert failed : %v", err)
    }

    password := "password"
    privateKey, cert, caCertificates, err := pkcs12.DecodeChain(b, password)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    pool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pool.AddCert(caCertificates[0])
    pool.AddCert(caCertificates[1])
    pool.AppendCertsFromPEM(rootCA)

    certificate := tls.Certificate{
        Certificate: [][]byte{cert.Raw},
        PrivateKey:  privateKey,
        Leaf:        cert}

    conf := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{certificate},
        RootCAs:      pool,
        MinVersion:   tls.VersionTLS11,
        ServerName:   "api.example.com"}

    transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: conf}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
    res, err := client.Post("api.example.com", "application/json", bufferObject)
```

Comment: The tls package supports [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#pkg-constants). Without more info there’s not much we can help with

Comment: You seem to be using the shorthand OpenSSL notations for the ciphersuites. Looking for the ones as specified in the TLS RFC's may give you better info.

Comment: Thank you both. I have updated with code.

Comment: A handshake failure can have lots of reasons, like cipher mismatch, missing or wrong client certificate, unsupported curves ... . Unfortunately this is hard to debug without having more information about client __and server__.  And yes, TLS error messages are usually not that helpful because in most cases all one gets  on the client side is that "something went wrong" and that's why the server is closing the connection. So please provide sufficient information so that others can actually reproduce this problem and then one could try to help better.

Comment: Yes that would help alot. Sadly, I dont have access to the server. I shall have to investigate further...

Answer (score 0):

So the solution turned out to be to use client.Do instead of http.Post

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "example.com/api", mockjson)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
```

Not sure about the internal differences